# How to generate time with format in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a request payload in which it accept a parameter in called `end-date` in the `Tue Jan 26 2021 12:00:00 GMT-0800` format.

So I want to always enter the next day of the current day or any day hence forth for example if I am running it today it should send either tomorrow or any additional day I have set in the format `Wed Jan 27 2021 12:00:00 GMT-0800` or `Tue Feb 2 2021 12:00:00 GMT-0800`.

How to achieve this in Jmeter ?

Comment: you can write a script in Groovy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To get current timestamp in an arbitrary format - [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time):

   ```
   ${__time(EE MM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss z,)}
   ```
2. To get any past/future date in an arbitrary format - [__timeShift() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift)

   ```
   ${__timeShift(EE MM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss z,,P1D,,)}
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
- [Creating Dates in JMeter Using the TimeShift Function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-dates-in-jmeter-using-the-timeshift-function)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I am getting the desired output `Fri Jan 29 2021 10:58:45 IST` but I want 
`Tue Jan 26 2021 12:00:00 GMT-0800`, is there any function which can convert it from local to GMT

Answer (score 0):

> is there any function which can convert it from local to GMT?

To also answer your sub question, try java code in any JSR223 component

```
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.ZoneId; 
import java.time.ZonedDateTime; 
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

ZonedDateTime zonedNow = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("GMT"))
ZonedDateTime dateTime = zonedNow.plus(Period.ofDays(2))
String dateTimeString = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz").format(dateTime);
log.info('>>>>> datetimeString: '+dateTimeString)
```

This is its result in log output

[image]